# There is no sound in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, alsa

Suddenly audio stopped working. It is not muted, output is set up for built in speakers.

When I connect earphones, Ubuntu does not detect device. I have installed [new packages from ALSA daily](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages)

Output for `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3241 Analog [ALC3241 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**Edit**

After reboot, Headphones are detected once plugged in, but still without the sound. So my built in speakers and headphones never play audio. Bluetooth speaker works fine when is paired.

**Edit 2**

In `alsamixer` I have Master  Headphon Speaker PCM  all for 100%

Auto-mute mode: disabled

**Edit 3**

I found temporary solution. When first time Ubuntu is booted, I do not have any sound. But when I do reboot and I go to BIOS Legacy settings, later exiting without saves... Ubuntu works with sounds. It is so weird. But is working. I am waiting for other solutions... appreciate any helpful anwsers

**Edit 4**

I have modified `alsa-base.conf` by adding line:

```
options snd_hda_intel enable=1 index=0
options snd_hda_intel enable=0 index=1
```

So now my `aplay -l` showed

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3241 Analog [ALC3241 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I though with one Playback Device it will work, but still no effects.

Comment: Try to set volume and output devices with `pavucontrol`. If it is not installed, you can install with `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`.

Comment: Everything is on 100% volume. Output device is setup for "Speakers", actually sound bar is moving, but there is no sound.